# How do I get an element with `aria-hidden` true out of a bunch of elements that have the same attribute?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a list of elements that all have `aria-hidden` set to either false or true, in my case, only one element has it set to true, so I need to know which one is currently visible.

Markup:

```
<div id="screen-1" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<div id="screen-2" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div id="screen-3" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

As such, I'd like to retrieve `screen-1`'s id:

```
var current_step = $('.setup-step-screen').each( function(i, obj) {
    if( $(obj).attr('aria-hidden') === 'false') {
        return $(obj).attr('id');
    }
});
console.log( current_step);
```

Problem is, this returns:

```
a.fn.init(2) [div#screen-1.setup-step-screen, div#screen-2.setup-step-screen, selector: ".setup-step-screen", prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document]
```

This is because it doesn't know when to stop the `each`, I believe, as such, this piece of code works:

```
var current_step;
$('.setup-step-screen').each( function(i, obj) {
    if( $(obj).attr('aria-hidden') === 'false') {
        current_step = $(obj).attr('id');
    }
});

console.log(current_step);
```

But I'd like to make the assignment within the `each`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `$('.setup-step-screen[aria-hidden="false"]')[0].id` (no loop needed).

Comment: I'm a bit confused: `in my case, only one element has it set to true` But you have *two* elements with `aria-hidden="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using vanilla JavaScript

You can use a CSS selector inside the method `.querySelector`. In your case

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[aria-hidden="false"]')
```

Will return all div elements that have `aria-hidden` set to `false`.

Here is the code:

```js
const selection = document.querySelectorAll('div[aria-hidden="false"]')

console.log(selection)
```

```html
<div id="screen-1" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<div id="screen-2" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div id="screen-3" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

---

### Using jQuery

If you want to use jQuery, the same can be applied:

```js
var current_step;
$('div[aria-hidden="false"]').each( function(i, obj) {
    current_step = $(obj).attr('id');
});

console.log(current_step);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen-1" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<div id="screen-2" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div id="screen-3" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what went wrong? -- I will use this as soon as I refactor my code. Using jQuery for prototyping.

Comment: You can't return anything with `each`, so the `return` statement inside the loop didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`, no library nor any loops required:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('[aria-hidden="false"]').id
);
console.log(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-hidden="true"]'),
    ({ id }) => id
  )
);
```

```html
<div id="screen-1" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<div id="screen-2" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div id="screen-3" class="setup-step-screen" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what went wrong? -- I will use this as soon as I refactor my code. Using jQuery for prototyping.

Comment: Whatever you `return` to an `.each` function will be ignored. You might use something like `.find` instead, or just use a selector and skip the looping.